# How to secure aluminium window lock handle that keeps falling off?

Tags: screws, mounting, aluminum

The lock handle on my aluminium windows keeps falling off. The handle had previously fallen off when I first moved in a year ago and the landlord remounted it. Since then it has become loose a few times, but has been able to be screwed back in. Now the two screws no longer hold. The internal thread (?) on the window frame is only a few millimetres thick.

How can I securely remount this handle?

I am not sure of the screw size/type, but below is a photo. [image: Handle]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The screw you're showing is a self-tapping metal screw.  It's designed to cut it's own channel into metal and grab hold by cutting it's own threads - but it's not meant for repeated uses because repeat uses can damage it's own threads, making its hole too big for it.

Take it to the local hardware store and get one that is slightly wider in diameter, and use it in place of the old one.

Comment: I'd add - take the lock along as well to make sure you get screws that aren't too wide for the hole in the lock.

Comment: Or drill out the lock hole as needed. Don't be limited by the lock, the screw must be big enough to stay in the oversized frame hole. That's the wrong screw anyway. You don't need self tapping for a typical aluminum window, a simple sheet metal screw will do. Also, the lock is counter sunk for flat or oval head screw, yet a round head was used.

Comment: @bcworkz - well spotted on the screw head. The only reason I mentioned about the size was that it could be hard to drill out the hole in the lock.

Comment: Yeah looks like this was a "replacement" screw poorly picked in the first place.

Comment: Two trips to the hardware store and not much luck. A #8 5/8" seems to fit okay, but the spacing between the threads is too great and the handle just wobbles about without falling out. Also tried a 1" thick bolt that is just a tad big. Dude at the store said I might need to resort to a rivet, but I reluctant to do so since I don't have the tools and am renting. Any other options?

Comment: Try a #10 1/2".  the #10 is the diameter, the 5/8 and 1" are length.  Length won't help you here, it's width you need to bite the walls of the window.  I doubt you could get inside the window frame to do a rivet anyway...not easily anyway.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, now that I actually think about it, the 1" thickness doesn't make any sense and not sure why I thought to increase the fraction (not used to imperial I guess). Not sure what width the other actually is (I think the guy said it was only half a mil thicker). Will try your suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: Ended up drilling new holes, but this seems like it would have worked if I could find the right screws.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: fit rivnuts in the openings and use machine screws. Should be stronger than the original, once you have the rivnuts in place. Setting rivnuts is a bit of a pain without the right tool, so you might actually want to buy a kit even if you don't have immediate use for most of it.

This does presume there is space for the rivnut to expand and lock in behind the old screw holes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to weld a piece of metal with thread on the existing hole location of the window frame. Than your problem solve.

Comment: While a welded doubler would certainly provide "meat" for the screw, welding to aluminum is a right pain in the arse compared to most things most folks on this site weld...

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with older windows.  I had them at my previous house.  The newer ones have more meat, as they are designed to a better standard.

Suggestion - Move the handle along by 15-20mm.  And use Loctite when you screw it in.

Comment: The ability to move the handle is predicated upon the ability to also move the lock into handle fits. For some windows, the lock is built into the frame, others it's attached (likely with rivets) and would be difficult to move

Answer (score 0):

I have used pop rivets in the past to secure handles onto old windows.  You would need to find the most appropriate rivet size to fit the handle.

Once you have done that, removing the handle will require drilling out the rivets.